# How does Arc access the underlying object without an extra field?

Tags: rust

I'm just learning Rust and run into an interesting phenomenon using `Arc`. With `Arc`, let's say I wrap a `vec` with `arc`, I can access that `vec` just as it was a normal `vec` without changing my code. For example:

```
let arc = Arc::new(vec![0,1,2,3]);
    
for x in arc.iter() {
    print!("{}", x);
}

// I can even call `len` as if it was a normal vector
println!("{}", arc.len());
```

I have some custom code which I am wrapping a vector and adding some custom logic on top of it.

```
struct Wrapper {
    underlying: Vec<i32>,
    my_custom_field_for_custom_logic: bool
}

// my wrapper
let wrap = Wrapper {
    underlying: vec![0,1,2,3],
    my_custom_field_for_custom_logic: true
};

for x in wrap.underlying.iter() {
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

For my structure, I have to use a special field called `underlying` to access the underlying vector.

I looked into `Arc`'s source code and found this:

```
pub struct Arc<T: ?Sized> {
    ptr: NonNull<ArcInner<T>>,
    phantom: PhantomData<ArcInner<T>>,
}
```

Essentially it has fields for underlying data as well. I'm new to rust, so the rest of the code goes way over my head.

So my question is essentially how can I make my `Wrapper` structure behave like `Arc`, in the sense that I can directly call vector methods (or methods of the underlying data) without accessing a special field.

Not a big deal, but I would like to know how it's done.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here: 1. Arc is not using the "newtype" pattern as far as I can tell, so does Deref apply here? 2. If Deref applies here, so Arc is implementing deref to access the underlying type, i thought that was bad practice?

Comment: Yes `Deref` can be used here. `Deref` is not always bad practice, it's a very useful tool, but for dedicated types. `Arc` is one of the "smart reference" types, it's used explicitly to work as a reference, so it makes sense to implement `Deref`.

Comment: Ahh, that's good to know. Thank you.

Comment: In addition to the linked QA, The [documentation for Deref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) has now this to say, in bold: **"Deref should only be implemented for smart pointers to avoid confusion."**

Comment: @DenysSéguret Do you know when that line was added? Deref is commonly implemented for non-pointer types even in std. For example it's implemented for owned counterparts of slice types: String, Vec, PathBuf etc. and I routinely implement it for similar types.

Comment: @PeterHall I'd say `String` and `PathBuf` can be considered smart pointers for `str` and `OsStr`, respectively, while `Vec` is also a smart pointer for a slice, `[T]`, so the statement is still mostly correct.

Comment: A lot of things can be considered "mostly correct" if you stretch out their meanings :)